# Extracting pixel values from keypoints generated by ORB in OpenCV Python

Tags: python, opencv

I have used OpenCV to find keypoints in an image which are stored in vector form in a variable named `kp`.  The code used for this:

```
#Read image and convert to greyscale
img = cv2.imread(DIR + i,0)
#Resize image to 100 x 100
r_g_img = cv2.resize(img, (100,100))
#Feature extraction
orb = cv2.ORB_create(scaleFactor=2, edgeThreshold=0)
kp = orb.detect(r_g_img,None)
kp,des = orb.compute(r_g_img,kp)
```

Now, when I look at the stored values for `kp` and `des` I see this:

```
>>> kp
    [<KeyPoint 05DA9318>, <KeyPoint 02F7A0C0>, <KeyPoint 02F7A098>, <KeyPoint 02F7ABB0>,...

>>> des
    array([[ 89,   4, 163, ...,  14, 116,  98],
    [ 17,  93,  81, ..., 184, 112, 173],
    [184,  85,  50, ...,  63,  52,  67],
    ..., 
    [  3, 216, 229, ...,  29,  88, 220],
    [163,  29,  71, ..., 124, 124,  86],
    [102,  92, 166, ..., 126, 244, 124]], dtype=uint8)
```

I'm not entirely sure what `des` is even referring to, but what I'm after are the pixel locations (x,y) of the keypoints.  When I pull up `kp` in the debugger watch window (see image below) I see the pixel values I'm after listed as `pt`.  What code can I use to grab those values?

[image: Snapshot of PyCharm Editor Watch Window]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [doc](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/modules/features2d/doc/feature_detection_and_description.html?highlight=orb#orb), I understand your `des` variable contains the descriptors of the keypoints. These descriptors are inspired from the BRIEF algorithm ([ORB paper](https://willowgarage.com/sites/default/files/orb_final.pdf)).

As for getting attributes of a KeyPoint, just do as you would for any Python object:

```
for keypoint in kp:
    print(keypoint.angle)
    print(keypoint.class_id)
    # ...
```

Comment: Thanks. New to Python so this nice to know. I was also interested in knowing exactly what a descriptor is.

Comment: You're welcome, I've edited my answer with a link to the paper by the authors, if you'd like to understand more about ORB's logic (I searched for the reference indicated in the opencv doc page).